# c# multiplying array elements using system.numerics

Tags: c#, simd, system.numerics

I'm experimenting with System.Numerics to multiple array elements. 
Is there a faster way of multiplying the element of the resultant vector (accVector) together?
Currently accVector needs to be converted to an array where the elements are multiplied together using LINQ.

```
        private double VectorMultiplication(double[] array)
        {
            int vectorSize = Vector<double>.Count;
            var accVector = Vector<double>.One;
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i <= array.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
            {
                var v = new Vector<double>(array, i);
                accVector = Vector.Multiply(accVector, v);
            }

            var tempArray = new double[Vector<double>.Count];
            accVector.CopyTo(tempArray);
            var result = tempArray.Aggregate(1d, (p, d) => p * d);

            for (; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                result *= array[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: in the last for loop `i` starts from `array.Length` because you didn't reset `i` to zero. Can you explain the logic behind these multiplications?

Comment: What you normally want the CPU do to is shuffle and vertical SIMD multiply until you reduce down to 1 scalar result.  Same as for horizontal sum but with mul instead of add: [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](//stackoverflow.com/q/6996764).  IDK if C# even makes it possible to narrow from 256 down to 128 as a first step, but log2(N) shuffle / mul steps is usually what you ideally want instead of store -> N-1 scalar multiplies, especially not with one long dependency chain.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a faster way of multiplying the element of the resultant vector (accVector) together?

Within Sytem.Numerics, no. As mentioned by Peter in the comments, usually you would start by splitting a 256bit vector into two 128bit halves and multiply them, then use shuffles to handle the 128bit part. But System.Numerics offers no shuffles, and it does not let you choose the size of the vector that you're using.

The usual approach *can* be used with the [System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86?view=netcore-3.1), which requires .NET Core 3.0 or higher.

For example:

```
static double product(Vector256<double> vec)
{
    var t = Sse2.Multiply(vec.GetLower(), vec.GetUpper());
    return t.GetElement(0) * t.GetElement(1);
}
```

That looks like it might be bad, leaving a mysterious `GetElement` up to the JIT engine to figure out, but actually the codegen is really reasonable:

```
 vmovupd     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rcx] 
 vextractf128 xmm0,ymm0,1  
 vmovupd     ymm1,ymmword ptr [rcx]  
 vmulpd      xmm0,xmm1,xmm0  
 vmovaps     xmm1,xmm0  
 vpshufd     xmm0,xmm0,0EEh  
 vmulsd      xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
```

So it looks like `GetElement(0)` is implicit and `GetElement(1)` results in a `vpshufd`, that's fine. Copying `xmm0` to `xmm1` instead of using a non-destructive `vpshufd` is a bit mysterious but not that bad, overall better than I normally expect of .NET.. I tested this function non-inlined, usually it should be inlined and the loads should go away.

---

The main loop can be improved, because the throughput of multiplication is much better than its latency. Right now the multiplications are done one at the time (that is, one *vector* multiplication at the time) with a delay in between (5 cycles on Haswell, 4 on Broadwell and newer) to wait for the previous multiplication to finish, but for example an Intel Haswell could be starting two multiplications per cycle which is 10 times as much. Realistically the improvement wouldn't be that big, but creating some opportunity for instruction level parallelism helps.

For example (not tested):

```
var acc0 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc1 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc2 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc3 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc4 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc5 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc6 = Vector<double>.One;
var acc7 = Vector<double>.One;
int i;

for (i = 0; i <= array.Length - vectorSize * 8; i += vectorSize * 8)
{
    acc0 = Vector.Multiply(acc0, new Vector<double>(array, i));
    acc1 = Vector.Multiply(acc1, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize));
    acc2 = Vector.Multiply(acc2, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize * 2));
    acc3 = Vector.Multiply(acc3, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize * 3));
    acc4 = Vector.Multiply(acc4, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize * 4));
    acc5 = Vector.Multiply(acc5, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize * 5));
    acc6 = Vector.Multiply(acc6, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize * 6));
    acc7 = Vector.Multiply(acc7, new Vector<double>(array, i + vectorSize * 7));
}
acc0 = Vector.Multiply(acc0, acc1);
acc2 = Vector.Multiply(acc2, acc3);
acc4 = Vector.Multiply(acc4, acc5);
acc6 = Vector.Multiply(acc6, acc7);
acc0 = Vector.Multiply(acc0, acc2);
acc4 = Vector.Multiply(acc4, acc6);
acc0 = Vector.Multiply(acc0, acc4);
// from here on it's the same
var tempArray = new double[Vector<double>.Count];
acc0.CopyTo(tempArray);
var result = tempArray.Aggregate(1d, (p, d) => p * d);
for (; i < array.Length; i++)
    result *= array[i];
```

This makes that last loop run potentially 8 times as much as it used to, that could be avoided by having an extra single-vector-per-iteration loop.

Comment: Thanks Harold. Do you have a sample code using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86 API that I can look at?

Comment: @little_stone_05 I added a bit

Comment: Weird that the JIT engine uses `vpshufd` between FP operations.  (Instead of `vshufpd` or `vunpckhpd`).  I think some AMD CPUs might have a bypass forwarding in that case.  (Intel doesn't.)

Comment: @harold how will you load the array into Vector256<double>?

Comment: @little_stone_05 with [LoadVector256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx.loadvector256?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_Intrinsics_X86_Avx_LoadVector256_System_Double__) for example